# sharepoint XsltListViewWebPart open hyperlink column in new window

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

Hopefully someone can provide a tip because I have a rather urgent issue.
I have the following XsltListViewWebPart:

```
        <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" Description="Test" ListDisplayName="" ImportErrorMessage="Error." PartOrder="0" HelpLink="" AllowRemove="True" IsVisible="True" AllowHide="True" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" ExportControlledProperties="False" IsIncludedFilter="" DataSourceID="" Title="Title" ViewFlag="8388621" NoDefaultStyle="" AllowConnect="True" FrameState="Normal" CatalogIconImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itdl.png" PageSize="-1" PartImageLarge="/_layouts/images/itdl.png" AsyncRefresh="False" Dir="Default" DetailLink="/Freigegebene Dokumente" ShowWithSampleData="False" ListId="84474224-4a76-471f-8e12-52f3185c4d72" ListName="{84474224-4A76-471F-8E12-52F3185C4D72}" FrameType="Default" PartImageSmall="" IsIncluded="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" AllowEdit="True" ViewGuid="{1B1FF0C7-CD99-4AFE-81E1-B1C2B3B08242}" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" AllowMinimize="True" WebId="f9888801-89f4-459b-9fe6-a6780d624ec9" ViewContentTypeId="0x" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" MissingAssembly="Error." HelpMode="Modeless" ListUrl="" ID="g_205870e9_70f2_4539_bbbf_a71b43f06783" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" AllowZoneChange="True" TitleUrl="/TitleUrl" ManualRefresh="False" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{1B1FF0C7-CD99-4AFE-81E1-B1C2B3B08242}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" __designer:CustomXsl="fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><ParameterBindings>
                                        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                                        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                                        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
                                        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                                        <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
                                        <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
                                        <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
                                        <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" />
                                        <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary)" />
                                        <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary_howto2)" />
                                    </ParameterBindings>
      <XmlDefinition>
                                        <View Name="{1B1FF0C7-CD99-4AFE-81E1-B1C2B3B08242}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="" Url="/SitePages/Homepage.aspx" Level="255" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png">
                                            <Query>
                                                <OrderBy>
                                                    <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef"/>
                                                </OrderBy>
                                            </Query>
                                            <ViewFields>
                                                <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/>
                                                <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/>
                                                <FieldRef Name="Modified"/>
                                                <FieldRef Name="Editor"/>
                                            </ViewFields>
                                            <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">15</RowLimit>
                                            <Toolbar Type="Freeform"/>
                                        </View>
                                    </XmlDefinition>
      <DataFields>
      </DataFields>
      </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

The field   "Editor" refers to a hyperlink column. How can I modify the above XsltListViewWebPart in order to make this column open in a new window? I dont need the exact solution, just some tip on what should i do, because right now im a bit clueless.

Thank you for your help.
Regards,

Comment: I found the issue. There was an option in Sharepoint Designer - Design View that inserts the whole XSLT for the XsltListViewWebPart. The problem was, that you first need to actually click inside the XsltListViewWebPart code, to make this Design option visible, with its insert XSLT option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. There was an option in Sharepoint Designer - Design View that inserts the whole XSLT for the XsltListViewWebPart. The problem was, that you first need to actually click inside the XsltListViewWebPart code, to make this Design option visible, with its insert XSLT option.